# Can't print only text using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup

I am struggling creating one of my first projects on python3. When I use the following code:

```
def scrape_offers():
    r = requests.get("https://www.olx.bg/elektronika/kompyutrni-aksesoari-chasti/aksesoari-chasti/q-1070/?search%5Border%5D=filter_float_price%3Aasc", cookies=all_cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    offers = soup.find_all("div",{'class':'offer-wrapper'})

    for offer in offers:
        offer_name = offer.findChildren("a", {'class':'marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink'})
        print(offer_name.text.strip())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_products.py", line 45, in <module>
    scrape_offers()
  File "scrape_products.py", line 40, in scrape_offers
    print(offer_name.text.strip())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2128, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I've read many similar cases on StackOverFlow but I still can't help myself. If someone have any ideas, please help :)

P.S.: If i run the code without `.text` it show the entire `<a class=...> ... </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findchildren returns a list. Sometimes you get an empty list, sometimes you get a list with one element.

You should add an if statement to check if the length of the returned list is greater than 1, then print the text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def scrape_offers():
    r = requests.get("https://www.olx.bg/elektronika/kompyutrni-aksesoari-chasti/aksesoari-chasti/q-1070/?search%5Border%5D=filter_float_price%3Aasc")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    offers = soup.find_all("div",{'class':'offer-wrapper'})

    for offer in offers:
        offer_name = offer.findChildren("a", {'class':'marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink'})
        if (len(offer_name) >= 1):
            print(offer_name[0].text.strip())

scrape_offers()
```